# Can we upload text file in big query?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have couple of  questions regarding big query:
1. Can we upload text files in google cloud platform and retrieve required data?? If yes how is it possible.
2.My main aim is to upload large amount of data to cloud platform analyse the data and retrieve the desired information whenever required. Data can be both structured and unstructured.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we upload text files in google cloud platform and retrieve
>   required data??

yes. You can

> If yes how is it possible

it is simple enough to get to this - You just need first to read below

BigQuery Home: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/
Quickstarts: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts
How-to Guides: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/how-to

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the help. However my question is once the text file is uploaded I want to retrieve the data in form of a database however  I am unable to figure out this it could be great if you could help me out with this.

Comment: what does mean - `data in form of database` ? I strongly recommend you to read first documentation , so then you will be able to ask specific and clear question